# Is there a way to display items of varying width in wpf wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying something like a windows 8 tiles and want to display tiles of varying width and/or height. `WrapPanel` makes each column equal width and height leaving blank spaces around the smaller items. Is there a way or a panel to display items much like a `StackPanel` where each items can have individual dimensions and wrap like a `WrapPanel`?

Edit:
This is my `ItemsControl`. I replaced the Tile DataTemplate with a simple `Border` and `TextBlock`. Width is `auto` and Tiles looks fine except `WrapPanel` create equal sized cells.

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contents}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="#B1DBFC" Height="200px" BorderBrush="#404648" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

[image: WrapPanel]

You can see from the image that the `width` of each column is the width of widest item.

If I set the width explicitly on the border, things get more ugly.
[image: Items with width set]

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can set varying heights/width of objects in a `WrapPanel` - See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) for an example. Are you doing something like using a `WrapPanel` inside an `ItemsControl`? If so, you need to set the Height/Width in the `ItemContainerStyle`, not on the item itself (see the bottom of [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) for an example/explanation)

Comment: Thanks for pointer, and yes I'm using `WrapPanel` inside an `ItemsControl`.I guess something else is causing the problem then.

Comment: If placing your `Height`/`Width` in the `ItemContainerStyle` doesn't work, can you update your question with your XAML code?

Comment: The codeproject reference you cited has items with equal width for vertical `Orientation`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour you are looking for is the *default* behaviour of the `WrapPanel` as can be seen from the following sample.

```
<WrapPanel >
    <WrapPanel.Resources>  
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Fill"
                    Value="#4DB4DD" />
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>

    <Rectangle Width="150" />
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle Width="200"/>
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle  Width="220"/>
    <Rectangle />
    <Rectangle />

</WrapPanel>
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

As you can see, The width of each item is honoured.

Your problem is caused by setting the orientation of the `WrapPanel` to `Vertical` in your template. This is laying out the items from top-to-bottom rather than left-to-right which means that it is the `Height` property that you need to be setting (or you could revert back to horizontal layout as in my example).

Compare your output to my screenshot where the panel is set to horizontal orientation; each **row** is the size of the highest `Rectangle`. Don't believe me? Try setting one of the `Rectangle's` `Height` property to a larger value and you will observe that the row size will increase and the `Rectangles` no longer line up vertically.

Reading your comments I think the best way to get started is to do the following:

- Have a `WrapPanel` that lays out its content horizontally.
- Items should have uniform `Height`.
- Constrain the `Height` of the `WrapPanel` to a certain size so that you don't get vertical scrollbars.

The height of your `WrapPanel` should be worked out using the following formula:

> ((Height of item + Top Margin + Bottom Margin) x Number of rows))

The width of each item also requires a bit of thought so that the panel lays the items out horizontally like the metro interface (lined up rather than staggered).

There are two tile sizes; the small one is 80px wide and the large one is 166px wide.
The width of the large tile is worked out like this:

> (item width * 2) + (left margin + right margin)

This ensures the tiles line up correctly.

So now my XAML looks something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="10,0">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="80" />
                <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="80" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="3" />
                <Setter Property="Fill"
                        Value="#4DB4DD" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,0,25,0" />
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
                        Value="516" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <WrapPanel Height="258">
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
        </WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel Height="258">
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="166" />
            <Rectangle />
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

This should give you enough information to start to re-factor this into a full control. If you do this then keep the following in mind:

- The layout properties (small item size, large item size, gaps etc) should be calculated rather than hard coded so that if you want to change, for example, the margins, the layout will still work correctly (I.E. the tiles will still line up).
- I would limit the number of 'tiles' that can be displayed (in the current example, if the tiles do not fit in the layout they are simply hidden which is probably not what you want).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case, I'm trying to avoid vertical scrolling similar to the windows 8 tiles. Any guidance in achieving the same with `WrapPanel`?

Comment: I would limit the width & height of the layout container and control the amount of items that are shown at a time to ensure that no scrolling would occur (I would do this for both horizontal and vertical orientation)

Comment: Ok, so there is no easy way to provide only horizontal scrolling while displaying items of different sizes? Any chance of you knowing about any other way I can achieve this effect?

Comment: Wrap the control in a horizontally oriented StackPanel. This would give you the scrolling and allow you to place your tiles in 'groups' like in the Metro interface.

Comment: But that will arrange the entire items in a single row leaving the rest of the screen blank.

Comment: Your suggestion is the way to go. Thanks for the guidance.